# R's tm package for word count

Tags: r, word-count, tm, corpus, text-analysis

I have a corpus with over 5000 text files. I would like to get individual word counts for each file after running pre-processing each (turning to lower, removing stopwords, etc). I haven't had any luck with the word count for the individual text files. Any help would be appreciated.

```
library(tm)
revs<-Corpus(DirSource("data/")) 
revs<-tm_map(revs,tolower) 
revs<-tm_map(revs,removeWords, stopwords("english")) 
revs<-tm_map(revs,removePunctuation) 
revs<-tm_map(revs,removeNumbers) 
revs<-tm_map(revs,stripWhitespace) 
dtm<-DocumentTermMatrix(revs)
```

Comment: Please add reproducible data set.  This is expected when you ask a question.

Comment: voting to close with no minimal working example

Answer (score 11):

As Tyler notes, your question is incomplete without a reproducible example. Here's how to make a reproducible example for this kind of question - use the data that comes built-in with the package:

```
library("tm") # version 0.6, you seem to be using an older version
data(crude)
revs <- tm_map(crude, content_transformer(tolower)) 
revs <- tm_map(revs, removeWords, stopwords("english")) 
revs <- tm_map(revs, removePunctuation) 
revs <- tm_map(revs, removeNumbers) 
revs <- tm_map(revs, stripWhitespace) 
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(revs)
```

And here's how to get a word count per document, each row of the dtm is one document, so you simply sum the columns for a row and you have the word count for the document:

```
# Word count per document
rowSums(as.matrix(dtm))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also do this in the [quanteda package](http://github.com/kbenoit/quanteda) that I developed with Paul Nulty.  It is easy to create your own corpus using the `quanteda` tools for this purpose, but it also imports `tm` VCorpus objects directly (as shown below).

You can get token counts per document using the `summary()` method for the corpus object type, or by creating a document-feature matrix using `dfm()` and then using `rowSums()` on the resulting document-feature matrix.  `dfm()` by default applies the cleaning steps that you would need to apply separately using the `tm` package.

```
data(crude, package="tm")
mycorpus <- corpus(crude)
summary(mycorpus)
## Corpus consisting of 20 documents.
## 
## Text Types Tokens Sentences
## reut-00001.xml    56     90         8
## reut-00002.xml   224    439        21
## reut-00004.xml    39     51         4
## reut-00005.xml    49     66         6
## reut-00006.xml    59     88         3
## reut-00007.xml   229    443        25
## reut-00008.xml   232    420        23
## reut-00009.xml    96    134         9
## reut-00010.xml   165    297        22
## reut-00011.xml   179    336        20
## reut-00012.xml   179    360        23
## reut-00013.xml    67     92         3
## reut-00014.xml    68    103         7
## reut-00015.xml    71     97         4
## reut-00016.xml    72    109         4
## reut-00018.xml    90    144         9
## reut-00019.xml   117    194        13
## reut-00021.xml    47     77        12
## reut-00022.xml   142    281        12
## reut-00023.xml    30     43         8
## 
## Source:  Converted from tm VCorpus 'crude'.
## Created: Sun May 31 18:24:07 2015.
## Notes:   .
mydfm <- dfm(mycorpus)
## Creating a dfm from a corpus ...
## ... indexing 20 documents
## ... tokenizing texts, found 3,979 total tokens
## ... cleaning the tokens, 115 removed entirely
## ... summing tokens by document
## ... indexing 1,048 feature types
## ... building sparse matrix
## ... created a 20 x 1048 sparse dfm
## ... complete. Elapsed time: 0.039 seconds.
rowSums(mydfm)
## reut-00001.xml reut-00002.xml reut-00004.xml reut-00005.xml reut-00006.xml reut-00007.xml 
##             90            439             51             66             88            443 
## reut-00008.xml reut-00009.xml reut-00010.xml reut-00011.xml reut-00012.xml reut-00013.xml 
##            420            134            297            336            360             92 
## reut-00014.xml reut-00015.xml reut-00016.xml reut-00018.xml reut-00019.xml reut-00021.xml 
##            103             97            109            144            194             77 
## reut-00022.xml reut-00023.xml 
##            281             43
```

I'm happy to help with any `quanteda`-related questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your question did not specify that you wanted only R-based solutions, so here is a really simple solution for counting your words in text files: using the Gnu utility `wc` at a Terminal or command line, with `-w` to specify words, e.g.

```sh
KB-iMac:~ kbenoit$ wc -w *.txt
       3 mytempfile.txt
       3 mytempfileAscii.txt
      14 tweet12.txt
      17 tweet12b.txt
      37 total
```

The numbers shown are word counts for this set of illustrative text files.

`wc` is included already on OS X and Linux, and can be installed for Windows from the [Rtools set](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this:

```
for (m in 1:length(revs) {
sum(nchar(as.character(revs[[m]])))
}
```